# Facebook app access removed

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk, android-facebook

I created a facebook app (say, FunLoginApp) under my organisation facebook account (say org@org.com) and this facebook account was the only administrator for this facebook app.

Everything worked fine and my users were successfully using the login with facebook functionality.

Recently, facebook recognized that the facebook account (org@org.com) is not an actual person and so disabled my account and asked me to migrate it to a facebook page which I did successfully.

But this somehow disabled the facebook app (FunLoginApp) under that account.
This is a CRITICAL issue as all 'Login with Facebook' clicks for my iOS and Android app are failing. and I am losing users, :(

I am unable to do anything as there is no way to reach my facebook app (FunLoginApp) or change any of the settings.

Please help me! any advice if someone ever were in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

I've contacted facebook. I posted on Facebook developers group and also posted a question as app-review question.

Facebook responded back to me, verified my account gmail address and made my personal facebook account as admin account through which i can access the app dashboard.

All resolved!